# Solving Complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

a is real number (not 0) 
n is natural number

$$(z + ai)^n - (z -ai)^n = 0$$

Every solution is real.

Determine solutions.

I have no idea

Comment: Hint. Draw an Argand diagram. Recall that $|w^n|=|w|^n$ and $\arg w^n=n\arg w\bmod 2\pi$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are solving for $z$, and  that $z$ is real.

If that is the case, call $z + a i = r e^{i\theta}$. Notice that  $z - a i = r e^{-i\theta}$

What the equation is saying is that

$r^n e^{i n \theta} = r^n e^{-i n \theta} $

The solution for that equation is $\theta = k \frac{\pi}{n}$, for $k=0,...,n-1$

Then, we know that $\tan(\theta) = \frac{a}{z}$, from there we can get $z=\frac{a}{\tan( k \frac{\pi}{n})}$ for $k=1,...,n-1$

Comment: I think that we are assuming z complex.

Comment: I'm using the polar representation of a complex number. It is explained here [link](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/polar-form-of-a-complex-number)

Comment: Now I got it !! Thx a lot.

Comment: @JorgeCatepillan I'm referring to your initial assumption "I'm assuming you are solving for z, and that z is real". I'm not sure that $z \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes. That was my initial thought but in the question, it is stated that "every solution is real".

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We have for $z\neq ai$

$$(z + ai)^n - (z -ai)^n = 0 \implies \frac{z + ai}{z -ai}=\omega_k, \; k=0,...,n-1$$

with $\omega_k$ the $k^{th}$ n-root of unity.